# UIViews not moving correctly during animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a viewcontroller with 3 UIViews that are stacked on top of each other. By stacked I mean at the bottom of one view, the next view begins. I have placed vertical constraints between each view with constant = 0. When the application begins, in `viewDidLoad`, I'm adding 500 to the vertical constraint between the two top views, so the bottom two views are pushed down below by doing:

```
billViewBottomConstraint.constant = 500
```

I then call the following function to animate the two bottom views moving back up, ending right below the top view:

```
func animate()
{

    self.billViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

The views certainly animate to the right position, but not the way I want. It looks like before the views animate, they are expanded outwards and when the animation is called they contract up and inwards towards the right position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `viewDidLoad`, the layout is not ready to be animated. You should wait at least until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to properly animate constraints. Check with a boolean to make sure it runs only for the first time.

```
fileprivate var firstLayoutSubviewsTime = true

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if firstLayoutSubviewsTime {
        firstLayoutSubviewsTime = false

        animate()
    }
}
```

You should call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` *before* the animation block to make sure all views are loaded properly.

You should also modify the constant **inside** the animation block, not before it.

```
func animate() {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
        self.billViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution out, but no animation occurred - all the views instantly appear in their final location. If I do `billViewBottomConstraint.constant = 500` followed by `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` without calling the animation block, the views appear in their correct position, shifted down 500. Not sure whats going on in the animation block thats causing this.